# Show that Weierstrass function is elliptic function.

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

Prove that Weierstrass function is periodic with respect to lattice $L (L\subset \mathbb{C})$ .i-e $f(z+w,L)=f(z,L)$ ($w\in L$).

$f(z,L)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{0\ne w\in L}\Big(\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}-\frac{1}{(w)^2}\Big)$

Comment: what is the definition of elliptic function you are using are you just trying to show that they are doubly periodic? Also please show your attempt as it will help people to understand where you are struck

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105112/532409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not difficult to see the periodicity of $f(z,L)$.

By definition  we have $f(z,L)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{0\ne w\in L}\Big(\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}-\frac{1}{(w)^2}\Big)$.

Let now $z+w_0$ with $w_0\in L-\{0\}$; then

$$f(z+w_0,L)=\frac{1}{(z+w_0)^2}+\sum_{0\ne w\in L}\Big(\frac{1}{(z+w_0-w)^2}-\frac{1}{(w)^2}\Big).$$

Since the sum run over $L-\{0\}$, and the lattice is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$, then $-w_0\in L$, hence we can rewrite $f(z+w_0,L)$ in this way:

$$f(z+w_0,L)=\frac{1}{(z+w_0)^2}+\frac{1}{(z+w_0-w_0)^2}+\sum_{0\ne w\in L; w\ne w_0}\frac{1}{(z+w_0-w)^2}-\sum_{0\neq w\in L}\frac{1}{(w)^2};$$

clearly $z+w_0-w_0=z$ and the piece $\frac{1}{(z+w_0)^2}$ can be incorporate in the first sum, so

$$f(z+w_0,L)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{w\in L; w\ne w_0}\frac{1}{(z+w_0-w)^2}-\sum_{0\ne w\in L}\frac{1}{(w)^2}.$$

Finally, since $L$ is a group the following sum are the same

$$\sum_{w\in L-\{0\}} \frac{1}{w^2}=\sum_{w_0-w \in L-\{0\}}\frac{1}{(w_0-w)^2},$$

and hence

$$f(z+w_0,L)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{w\in L; w\ne w_0}\Big(\frac{1}{(z+w_0-w)^2}-\frac{1}{(w_0-w)^2}\Big).$$

With abuse of notation we can call the different $w_0-w$ as $w$; clearly $w_0-w\ne 0$ imply $w\ne 0$ and rewrite the sum:

$$f(z+w_0,L)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{0\ne w\in L}\Big(\frac{1}{(z-w)^2}-\frac{1}{(w)^2}\Big)=f(z,L).$$

Comment: can you sir explain why you first write omega not equal to minus omega not.... i think it should be omega not equal to omega not....i think there is no need of minus sign there... @Gianluca Faraco

Comment: Yes, you right! :) Now I edit my post.

Comment: I don't think this is correct since neither sum in the second display converge. You have to go through the derivative to show periodicity, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/a/924286/159642

Comment: @häxq I don't understand which sum doesn't converge.. Anyway, I have just manipulated the definition of $f(z,L)$ and I used the group property of $L$. Nothing more.

Comment: @InsideOut The sum $\sum_{\omega} (z-\omega)^{-2} - \omega^{-2}$ converges since the summand is of order $\omega^{-3}$ but the two sums $\sum_\omega (z-\omega)^{-2}$ and $\sum_\omega \omega^{-2}$ do not as the summand is of size $\omega^{-2}$.